# which event should i use TextView or ListView event

Tags: android, listview, textview, contacts

I have a list of contacts available in list view now when ever user click on list i want to show edit option, as i am new to android i dont know on which event i should write code.

i tried with listview event as setOnItemClickListener but its giving me error when i tried to used suggested option but still its showing me error please help me.

Comment: I am not understand your problem what you want please describe in detail then i hope i will give you a perfect answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
    // In OnCreate() call this
    registerForContextMenu(yourlistview);

   @Override
   public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)
    {
        menu.setHeaderTitle("Choose an option");
        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Edit");
        menu.add(0, 1, 0, "Something Else");

        super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    }


    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)
    {
        AdapterContextMenuInfo menuInfo = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
        switch ( item.getItemId() )
        {
        case 0: 

             ListView listView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.yourlist);

             // In my example i've used a string. Do not use copy pasta. yeah ? 
             String S = (String) listView.getAdapter().getItem(menuInfo.position);
```

This is a [context menu](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html). Read up on it. You'll get the idea.

Comment: thanks but now i am facing problem with RegisterForContextMenu(Textview).. i am showing a list of contacts when ever user long pressed it i want to show context menu. but while debugging i observe that my application crashes as it comes to above line please help me..

Comment: Oi Neha [read the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html). registerForContextMenu(lv) takes a listview as an input. Don't use code blindly.

Comment: ohh thanks, but still m not able to solve problem as want id of the selected contact what to do for that.please guide me.

Comment: That's because you did not read the code in my answer. From the item position you can use the mapping between the Adapter dataset and ListView item to get the Contact Id. (If you don't understand what I said its about time you read a book on android programming.)